# How to run a client function when page reloads?

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm having a hard time figuring out how can I do a simple "auto-login" where I re-attach the JWT Token to axios ... **what I can't figure out is** where to write so it can be called first thing when someone refreshes a page...

in "plain" VueJS, one can hook to the application `created` event, like

```js
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  created() { /* application created hook */ },
  render: h => h(app)
}).$mount('#app')
```

but in Nuxt, how do we accomplish the same?

I've tried running with **client Middleware** and a **client Plugin** as well, but they don't run client mode upon refresh, only run in server mode...

What is the correct way of running code in the client upon page refresh?

---

**Added setup** for better understanding what have I done

I have 2 examples **middlewares** as:

```js
// FILE ./middleware/authenticated.js
export default function (ctx) {
    console.log('[MIDDLEWARE] Authenticated, is client:', process.client)
}
```

and

```js
// FILE ./middleware/refreshToken.js
export default function (ctx) {
    console.log('[MIDDLEWARE] Refresh token, is client:', process.client)
}
```

and I have my layout with:

```js
export default {
    components: { ... },
    middleware: ['refreshToken', 'authenticated'],
    ...
}
```

I've also added a **plugin**

```js
// FILE ./plugins/auth.js
export default function (ctx) {
    console.log('[PLUGIN] Auth, is client:', process.client)
}
```

and set it up as `plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/auth' }], ...`

nothing runs on the Client... all runs in Server mode only (and I can' access `localStorage` in server mode - I can, ultimately use Cookies so I can read it from the server, but it's not the point)

the output is:

```sh
[PLUGIN] Auth, is client:  false
[MIDDLEWARE] Refresh token, is client: false
[MIDDLEWARE] Authenticated, is client: false
```

How can I run any code, in client-mode, upon page refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using SSR, middleware is running on the server side on the initial request (e.g. when reloading the page).

A client side plugin, for example `~plugins/refresh.client.js` will serve your needs and runs only once when the page has been loaded but on the client side.

PS: Don’t forget to register it in your Nuxt config.

Comment: so MIDDLEWARE only runs server-side ... my issue is that I actually have a middleware that redirects the user to `/login` if no store data exists (page refresh), and that runs prior than the Plugin, so I need to create a plugin for that redirect and not a middleware, correct?

Comment: Middleware runs on both sides. Initial request ~> server side, further navigation ~> client-side ☺️

So yes, you’d want to create a plugin for that check & redirect 